# Create Redshift UDF that can query from a table

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, replace, amazon-redshift

I need to replace an input string with values from a table in Redshift

I have this function in SQL that replaces the input string with values from a table. I can't make it work in Redshift because it doesn't accept the FROM clause. Thoughts?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StringReplace](@str VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @str = REPLACE(UPPER(@str),find,sub)
    FROM [dbo].[StringReplace]

    RETURN @str
END
```

I tried converting it, but not no luck and I can't think of a way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Same as [Using a table in python UDF in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68203665/174777) -- it isn't possible to access a table from within a User-Defined Function in Amazon Redshift. The alternate way would be to keep all the string replacements within the UDF code so it doesn't need to access a table.

Comment: The table that has the replacements is like 500 rows. That doesn't seem like a tenable idea.

Comment: You could code it as a Python UDF with a `{map}` of replacements. Your choice!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I am kinda new at this, so if you could provide an example that would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but you could create a Python UDF that substitutes the strings. Something like:

```
create or replace function substitute (in_string varchar)
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
words = {'APARTMENT': 'APT', 'ARCADE': 'ARC', 'BASEMENT': 'BSMT', 'BUILDING': 'BLDG', 'DEPARTMENT': 'DEPT', 'WEST': 'W', 'STREET': 'ST'}

return ' '.join(words.get(word, word) for word in in_string.upper().split())

$$ language plpythonu;
```

Use it like this:

```
select name, substitute(name) from table
```

Comment: It seems to just return the input string without replacing the words unfortunately. Is there anyway you could send me a working function?

Comment: Sounds like the "function creation" part works. The Python part works for me outside of Redshift, so not sure what's upsetting it. Unfortunately I don't have a Redshift instance on which to test it.

Comment: I found code that seems to take your idea, but I don't know how to put the code into a function.
````test_str = 'geeksforgeeks is best'
 
map_dict = {'e': '1', 'b': '6', 'i': '4'}
 
new_str = ''.join([map_dict.get(char, char) for char in test_str])````

Comment: Oh! I assumed you just wanted to replace one word, which was the whole string. Are you saying that you want to replace multiple words within the input string? Is there the possibility that a 'destination' string might contain a 'source' string (making it difficult to loop through the replacement words)? For example, might `ABC` be converted into `DEF`, but then `EF` is converted to `GH`, making `DGH` instead of the desired `DEF`? (Us programmers get pedantic!)

Comment: Yes like an address input string. So example, 123 WEST MAIN STREET would become 123 W MAIN ST. We would have values of WEST:W and STREET:ST.

Comment: How would you prevent every `WEST` becoming `W`? For example, `WESTERN` should not change to `WERN`. Are you only replacing whole words? What are the word delimiters?

Comment: We have a table that has values like this. We only want to replace the entire word.
APARTMENT   APT 
 ARCADE   ARC 
 BASEMENT   BSMT 
 BUILDING   BLDG 
 DEPARTMENT   DEPT

Comment: Okay, it is now updated to find words split by spaces. Punctuation might impact it, so be careful!

Comment: You rock my friend! Thanks for taking the time to help.